# Ghostscript error when using both pst-rputover & tcolorbox

Tags: pstricks, tcolorbox, ghostscript

I can compile (no errors) the following MWE (file.tex) on
TL-2019 (linux) with both latex & pdflatex <-shell-escape>:

```
\documentclass{article}% 
%
\usepackage[on]{pstricks-pdf}% 
\usepackage{lipsum,pst-rputover,tcolorbox}% 
%
\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1]
\par\bigskip
\begin{tcolorbox}[center,colback=gray!20]%
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.5,-1.25)(4.5,2.5)%
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow!20](-2,2)(0,0)(4,0)%
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2,2)(0,0)%
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2,2)(4,0)%
\psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0,0)(4,0)%
\psline[linecolor=blue](-2,2)(2,0)% AM
\psdots[linecolor=blue,dotsize=2pt 0](2,0)%
\rput[tl](1.8,-0.15){$M$}%
\psdots[linecolor=blue,dotstyle=*](4,0)%
\rput[bl](3.87,-0.4){$\mathbf{C}$} %
\psdots[linecolor=blue,dotstyle=*](0,0)%
\rput[bl](-0.14,-0.4){$\mathbf{B}$}%
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](-2,2)%
\rput[bl](-2.15,2.15){$\mathbf{A}$}%
\pnode(0,-0.75){U}%
\pnode(2,-0.75){V}%
\pnode(4,-0.75){X}%
%
\rputover(U)(V){$m$}%
\rputover(V)(X){$n$}%
\coverable{%
\pcline[linewidth=0.2pt,tbarsize=5pt]{|-}(U)(V)%
\pcline[linewidth=0.2pt,tbarsize=5pt]{|-|}(V)(X)%
}%
%%  uncoverable version
%\pcline[linewidth=0.2pt,tbarsize=5pt]{|-}(U)(V)\ncput*{$m$}%
%\pcline[linewidth=0.2pt,tbarsize=5pt]{|-|}(V)(X)\ncput*{$n$}%
%
\end{pspicture*}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
\par\bigskip
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Both evince file.pdf & xpdf file.pdf show a flawless output.

gv file.ps shows a corrupt output:
Error: typecheck in restore
...
Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
(1st paragraph & picture are shown, 2nd paragraph vanishes;
evince file.ps gives a blank page)

Commenting out either `%begin{tcolorbox}...%\end{tcolorbox}` or

```
%\coverable{% 
... 
%}%
```

would get rid of that error, but with a different output as seen in file.pdf.

Can anyone reproduce this kind of error and tell what's going on?

Tia, Ed.

Comment: `tcolorbox` is based on Ti*k*Z. So why don't you just draw the picture with Ti*k*Z? This will reduce the code substantially.

Comment: This is a book with many pictures converted to Pstricks by Geogebra. I'd like to understand that specific error and if it's possible to get rid of it.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,blue,inner sep=1.5pt}]
 \draw[very thick,fill=yellow!20,line join=round] (-2,2) node[bullet,label=above:\textbf{A}](A){}
 --(0,0) node[bullet,label=below:\textbf{B}](B){} 
 --(4,0) node[bullet,label=below:\textbf{C}](C){}--cycle;
 \draw (2,0.1) -- (2,-0.1) node[below](M){$M$};
 \draw[blue] (2,0) -- (A);
 \path (B|-0,-1) -- (M|-0,-1) node[midway] (m){$m$}
 (M|-0,-1) -- (C|-0,-1) node[midway] (n){$n$};
 \draw[|-] (B|-0,-1) -- (m);
 \draw[|-] (M|-0,-1) -- (m);
 \draw[|-] (C|-0,-1) -- (n);
 \draw[|-] (M|-0,-1) -- (n);
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger's cat, but no need suggesting a replacement for pstricks/tcolorbox such as \psframe, \fbox, mdframed, TikZ, etc. The question is about the Ghostscript error when using pst-rputover & tcolorbox.

Answer (score 2):

The `dvips` driver from `TikZ` is buggy. Use *always* `pdflatex --shell-escape` or `xelatex` or use an own frame macro:

```
\documentclass{article}% 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}% 
\usepackage{lipsum,pst-rputover,tcolorbox}% 
\def\PBox#1{%
  \psframebox[fillcolor=gray!20,fillstyle=solid,framearc=0.1,linewidth=2pt,linecolor=black!60]{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\psframesep-4pt]{#1}}}

\begin{document} 
    \lipsum[1]
    \par\bigskip\noindent
    \PBox{%
        \begin{pspicture*}(-4.5,-1.25)(4.5,2.5)%
        \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow!20](-2,2)(0,0)(4,0)%
        \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2,2)(0,0)%
        \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](-2,2)(4,0)%
        \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](0,0)(4,0)%
        \psline[linecolor=blue](-2,2)(2,0)% AM
        \psdots[linecolor=blue,dotsize=2pt 0](2,0)%
        \rput[tl](1.8,-0.15){$M$}%
        \psdots[linecolor=blue,dotstyle=*](4,0)%
        \rput[bl](3.87,-0.4){$\mathbf{C}$} %
        \psdots[linecolor=blue,dotstyle=*](0,0)%
        \rput[bl](-0.14,-0.4){$\mathbf{B}$}%
        \psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](-2,2)%
        \rput[bl](-2.15,2.15){$\mathbf{A}$}%
        \pnode(0,-0.75){U}%
        \pnode(2,-0.75){V}%
        \pnode(4,-0.75){X}%
        %
        \rputover(U)(V){$m$}%
        \rputover(V)(X){$n$}%
        \coverable{%
            \pcline[linewidth=0.2pt,tbarsize=5pt]{|-}(U)(V)%
            \pcline[linewidth=0.2pt,tbarsize=5pt]{|-|}(V)(X)%
        %%  uncoverable version
        %\pcline[linewidth=0.2pt,tbarsize=5pt]{|-}(U)(V)\ncput*{$m$}%
        %\pcline[linewidth=0.2pt,tbarsize=5pt]{|-|}(V)(X)\ncput*{$n$}%
        %
    }
        \end{pspicture*}%
    }%
    \par\bigskip
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I said, pdflatex compiles fine. I'll take this as an answer. Hopefully this bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: I've just seen question 470077. Help is on the way.

Comment: I do not think that it belongs to 470077. That was another problem which was fixed, as far as I remember.